# Xrdp set up connection outside of localhost

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed xrdp on my ubuntu 14.04, so I have connect to my computer by Remmina from another ubuntu computer.

How can I connect to computer with xrdp remotely, not from localhost network (127.*.*.* or 192.*.*.*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was need just to make a port forwarding on my computer